# Javascript calculates large integers incorrectly

Tags: javascript

I am making a program about the formula 10^(a-1)-1 mod a = 0. However, when using Javascript, it doesn't work with numbers for a above 23. Example:

```
var b = 29
var a = Math.pow(10, b-1)

console.log(a);
console.log(a/b);
console.log(a % b)
```

This is the output:

```
1e+28
3.448275862068965e+26
14
```

The output for the modulo function should be 1. Is there any way to make it solve the calculations correctly?

Comment: `console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BigInt`.

```js
var b = 29n;
var a = 10n ** (b - 1n);
console.log(a.toString());
console.log((a/b).toString());
console.log((a % b).toString());
```